# Why won't my foreign key create in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I've tried many different ways to create table with a foreign key and trying to insert into phpMyAdmin. However, it just not working as I was expected.

Here are what I've so far:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    user_id BIGINT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    user_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    user_password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);
```

This works perfectly fine. However, if I try to add a table with a foreign key thus, it refuses to create:

```
CREATE TABLE article (
    article_id INT(20) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    article_title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    article_content VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    user_id INT(10) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (user_id));
```

This would not work as expected and would not add the table to the MySQL database. I get this error:

> Cannot add foreign key constraint

How can I fix it?

Comment: What happens if you put in the second query? Do you get an error? If so, what error do you get? (Both queries appear to have a trailing double-quote mark, which would cause a syntax error. If you are adding that into phpMyAdmin, then remove it - that may be your problem).

Comment: Why use `INT(20)` instead of `BIGINT(20)`. Also why `VARCHAR(1000)` instead of just `TEXT` or `BLOB` data type?

Comment: Ah! Your `article` table is missing a definition for `user_id` - you need to explicitly define that before declaring the `FOREIGN KEY`.

Comment: Ok maybe that's the problem. @halfer can you give an example of with definition for user_id?

Comment: Just add a definition above the FK, something like `user_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,` so that it matches the definition of the primary key in the other table.

Comment: @halfer Thanks, however, it is still not adding the table. I've tried like "PRIMARY KEY (article_id), FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (user_id))" and it still not adding

Comment: Well, I've already asked you for an error message, how about letting us know what it is?

Comment: Ah, that should have been `UNSIGNED` - [this works fine](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/711325). As per my previous comment, it is good to get into the habit of offering as much detail as possible, so that people helping are not left wondering what the problem is. In this case I worked it out, but in general it can speed up the answering process a great deal if the necessary information is provided in the first instance.

Comment: @halfer Thanks a lot for your help, it's working now. Also Thanks for your advice on the questing process, I will do that more often.

Answer (score 1):

We discovered in the comments that if a primary key is defined thus:

```
user_id BIGINT(10) UNSIGNED
```

then a foreign key like this will not work, since it needs to match on signedness (and I think type too):

```
user_id INT(10) NOT NULL
```

This works fine:

```
user_id BIGINT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/711325) to demonstrate it working.